# Reduce space between numbers and paths in "dirs -v" output

Tags: zsh, output

I feel like the space between the numbers and the paths is too much and I believe that less space would make lines easier to follow.

Is there an easy way reduce that space?

[image]

Comment: That space is [actually a single tab char](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Src/builtin.c#L762)... Replace `head -10`  with `sed 's/[[:blank:]]/  /;10q'`...

Comment: Awesome, does the job perfectly! What's the second part of the sed value called the one that limits lines to 10 - `10q`, I'd love to find out more about that. Thanks!

Comment: It's explained in the manual (`man sed`)... `10q` means `q`uit when on line no. `10`

Comment: `dir -v | column -t` can help.

Comment: @jimmij, it does! Produces the ideal output. Thanks for the thoughtful suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a TAB, you see a 7 column gap because your terminal has tab stops every 8 columns.

You could change the tabstop spacing on the terminal with for instance:

```
tabs 4
```

To set the tab stops every 4 columns instead of 8, or pipe the output to:

```
expand -t4
```

To convert TABs to spaces with tabstops every 4 column. Or

```
expand -t4,/8
```

To expand the tabs but with the first after the 4th column, and the other ones every 8 column as usual.

Or convert the first TAB to one space (but beware it would misalign the output when you display more than 10 lines) by piping to:

```
sed $'s/\t/ /'
```

Answer (score 1):

quick'n dirty

```
dirs -v| sed -r 's/\s{2,}/ /'
```

Comment: Awesome, could you please explain what each part does? Thanks!